# Xamarin iOS App Stuck with "invisible" build

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, app-store-connect, application-loader

I'm publishing my first Xamarin.iOS app to the store. I've set up my distribution profiles, set up the app on iTunes connect, and all seems well. I published my app for archiving and then successfully uploaded via the Application Loader.

What's broke is that iTunes Connect doesn't see my app - it says I still need to upload via Xcode or Application Loader... but when I try to upload my IPA (again) via the Application loader ("sign and distribute" via Xamarin), I get the error "ERROR ITMS-4238: "Redundant Binary Upload. There already exists a binary upload with build version '1.0' for train '1.0'" at SoftwareAssets/PreReleaseSoftwareAsset."

I don't see an option in ITunesConnect to delete this build and start over with another version, and it won't let me Submit for Review because it doesn't see the build as being uploaded.

I've opened a ticket with Apple over a week ago and haven't heard back. I know I could go with a different AppId but for all I know I'll hit the same wall. Anybody been down this road?

**UPDATE #1**

I've created version 1.1 of my app and uploaded it successfully to ITC. I see it in the Builds section (still don't see 1.0) but I can't add a new version of the app to "link" this build to because v1.0 is still "Preparing to Submit"

Apps - unable to create v1.1 while v1.0 is "Preparing to Submit."

[image: Unable to create a new version]

Builds - v1.0 is not visible, but if I try to reupload ITC says it's there

[image]

**UPDATE #2**

I was able to link v1.0 of my app store submission to v1.1 build and submit the app for review. I don't know if this will go through or not, but it was at least submitted. I am now also able to "reject" this version, but if I do this I'm unable to add another version still (if I wanted to get a clean v1.1).

[image: Unable to add new version after Developer Rejected]

Comment: Now that you have managed to get it submitted to review then you should be good. Just cross your fingers that when they get around to it in a week or two that they won't reject it for something trivial. The review process can be a bit of a gamble.

Answer (score 0):

Each build you upload must have a unique build number. So if you upload 1.0 then the next must be 1.1 etc. What I do is keep the internal test builds with an extra .1 at the end so my internal would be 1.1.1, 1.1.2 etc and then I'll push 1.2 to the store when ready. You can also change the version number on your App's settings on iTunes Connect. They wont reject it as it's just the build number.